# Calculating distance and angle between polynomials

Tags: polynomials, continuity, inner-products, angle

I am having trouble finding the distance and angle between two polynomials in the space of continuous functions over the interval $[0,1]$. The inner product of this space is defined as:

$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{0}^{1} f(t) g(t) dt$$

The two polynomials in question are $p(t) = 1+t$ and $q(t) = 1+t^2$.

I have tried to use the formula for the distance between two vectors in an inner product space:

$$\|p-q\| = \sqrt{\langle p-q, p-q\rangle }$$

However, when I apply this formula to the given polynomials, I end up with a non-zero answer. I suspect that I am doing something wrong or missing a step.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to correctly calculate the distance and angle between these polynomials.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course that you would get a nonzero distance between two different polynomials. Just the same as the distance in an Euclidean space would be nonzero between two different points!

Comment: Since they are different polynomials, you *should* end up with a non-zero (and positive) answer for the distance between them.

Comment: Also, when typing angle brackets, use `\langle` for $\langle$ and `\rangle` for $\rangle$. The signs $<$ and $>$ don't look as nice.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand now that the distance between two different polynomials in this space should be non-zero. However, I am still unsure how to calculate the distance and angle between these two specific polynomials. Could you please provide some guidance on how to proceed with the calculation?

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding the angle brackets, I will keep that in mind for future posts.

Comment: The method you described for calculating the distance is correct.  You could add what distance you got if you want someone to check it for you, but it seems that you're going about this correctly.  And the formula for the angle is $ \angle ( p , q ) = \arccos \bigg ( \frac { \langle p , q \rangle } { \| p \| \, \| q \| } \bigg ) $, which comes from $ \langle p , q \rangle = \| p \| \, \| q \| \cos \angle ( p , q ) $.  (PS: And you can use `\|` instead of `||` to get a better double vertical bar for norms, although this is not as significant as `\langle` and `\rangle` vs `<` and `>`.)

Comment: @TobyBartels Thank you for your help. Using the formula for the distance between two vectors in an inner product space, I obtained:

$$
\begin{aligned}
||p-q|| &= \sqrt{\langle p-q, p-q\rangle} \\
&= \sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}(1+t-t^2)^2 dt} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{41}{30}} \approx 1.16905
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: @TobyBartels And using the formula for the angle between two vectors in an inner product space, I obtained:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos\angle(p, q) &= \frac{\langle p, q\rangle}{\|p\|\|q\|} \\
&= \frac{\int_{0}^{1}(1+t)(1+t^2)}{\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}(1+t)^2}\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}(1+t^2)^2}} \\
&= \frac{25 \sqrt{5}}{56} \approx 0.998
\end{aligned}
$$

Is this correct? And $$\arccos \left(\frac{25 \sqrt{5}}{56}\right) \cdot \frac{180}{\pi} = 3.39535°$$

Comment: $p-q = t-t^2$, not $1 + t - t^2$

Comment: @Bishop_1 :  For $ \| p - q \| $, Paul has already made a comment spotting an error.  Your calculation for the angle is correct, although I've never seen an angle given in degrees in this context; the geometric analogy is pretty strained by this point, so people usually (in my experience) keep it in radians (or even just report the cosine and leave it at that).  Incidentally, you can check your two results by testing $ \| p - q \| ^ 2 = \| p \| ^ 2 + \| q \| ^ 2 - 2 \| p \| \, \| q \| \cos \angle ( p , q ) $ (which geometrically, is the Law of Cosines).